# Using composer package inside Laravel Nova tool

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have created a simple demo Laravel Nova Tool to fetch some remote data. I need to fetch it with PHP as it requires authorization, anyway this code inside api.php:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

Route::get('/employees', function (Request $request) use ($client) {

     $base_url = 'https://example.com';
     $get_token_url = $base_url . '/auth/access_token?user_id=smthg&user_secret=smthg';

     $request = $client->get($get_token_url);
     $response = $request->getBody();

     return $response;
 });
```

It doesn't work as I'm getting `Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found.` I need this dependency inside the Tool. I have installed Guzzle using `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` inside the Tool and composer.json is updated accordingly. It is a namespace issue. My question is how can I correctly namespace it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the slash before `GuzzleHttp\Client.` Also, the `$request` parameter gets overridden. In your routes `api.php` try this instead.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

Route::get('/employees', function (Request $request) use ($client) {
    $base_url = 'https://example.com';
    $get_token_url = $base_url.'/auth/access_token?user_id=smthg&user_secret=smthg';
    $response = $client->get($get_token_url);

    return $response->getBody();
});
```